# Accessing list element without for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

Lets say I have this list

```
x = [1,10,5,4]
```

and I want to add `1` for each item of the list. So, the output will be

```
x = [2, 11, 6, 5].
```

Is there any easy way to do it without using for loop?

Comment: Why the 'no loops' requirement? You *have* to loop to apply a change to each element. That loop can be delegated to something like `map()` but it still has to be done.

Comment: Also, have you tried anything yourself yet? What worked, what didn't?

Comment: Whatever you do, your code must loop in somewhere...

Comment: Sorry may be I had to say delicate way. `map()` is absolutely perfect.

Comment: Actually map is slower than a list comprehension. In what way is it perfect?

Comment: I just have list of max length of `4`. So, I just needed something to look neat in my code.

Comment: List comprehensions are considered neater and more pythonic than map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
x = [1,10,5,4]
x = map(lambda y: y+1, x)
```

Comment: oh yeah! but not in python)

Answer (score 2):

What a ridiculous requirement

```
x = [x[0]+1, x[1]+1, x[2]+1, x[3]+1]
```

The easy way *is* with loops

Using `map`

```
x = map(1 .__add__, x)
```

but then most people would call that a loop

Comment: Queue the comment by the OP asking how to do this when `x` has an unknown number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

Loops are good. List comprehensions are great.

```
x = [e+1 for e in x]
```

As koffein said, it is even faster than the map function:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("[e+1 for e in x]","x = list(range(100))",number=100000)
0.7970689787364194
>>> timeit.timeit("map((1).__add__,x)","x = list(range(100))",number=100000)
0.8699621167282174
>>> timeit.timeit("map(y,x)","x=list(range(100));y=lambda x:x+1",number=100000)
1.8961955365813026
```

Comment: It is even a little faster than `map((1).__add__, x)` and almost two times faster than the map-and-lambda version...

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```
y = lambda x: x+1

x = [1,10,5,4]

map(y, x)
```